# HTML right click drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to implement 2 list view, where I have to press right mouse button on one list and drag the item to other list.

Using HTML5 and angular 2 library its working with left mouse button but not getting much how to enable drag event on right mouse button, as draggable="true" only working for left mouse button.

Is there any way to enable drag event on right mouse button click

Comment: You haven't tried anything yourself?

Comment: implemented the same stuff using left mouse click using html5 attributes draggable= true, but not getting how to make it work for right mouse button.

Comment: show your current code

Comment: most efficient library I found and worked for left mouse drag event : http://akserg.github.io/ng2-webpack-demo/#/dnd

Comment: OT: right click is fine with a desktop mouse but very annoying with a laptop (and for a keyboard user whether hardcore developer or non-sighted user)